# Python, Serial не отправляется команда

Tags: python, serial

Мне нужно через Raspberry Pi через устройство `/dev/ttyAMA0` отослать, к примеру, символ `с`. Для этого, как и в документации `pySerial`, я написал мини код:

```
import serial

def send_tty():
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 115800)
print(ser.name)
ser.write(b'c')
return
```

При выполнении `ser.write(b'c')` получаю `1` и никакого эффекта на экране.
Есть ли другие модули в `Python`, которые позволяют нормально пересылать команды в `TTY/UART` или как сделать это с этим?

Comment: А вы со скоростью не ошиблись, `115800` странная скорость, обычно используют `115200`.

Comment: @Avernial даже скорость не помогла добиться правильного эффекта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе, у вас тут всё нормально.
Это должно работать.

Единственное, что, может быть, параметры порта не подходят (скорость, чётность и т.д.)

Вот более развёрнутый пример, где видно как выставлять параметры
порта, как работать с ним, как считывать данные в ответ и так далее:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial, time
#initialization and open the port

#possible timeout values:
#    1. None: wait forever, block call
#    2. 0: non-blocking mode, return immediately
#    3. x, x is bigger than 0, float allowed, timeout block call

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB7"
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
#ser.timeout = None          #block read
ser.timeout = 1            #non-block read
#ser.timeout = 2              #timeout block read
ser.xonxoff = False     #disable software flow control
ser.rtscts = False     #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
ser.dsrdtr = False       #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
ser.writeTimeout = 2     #timeout for write

try: 
    ser.open()
except Exception, e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()

if ser.isOpen():

    try:
        ser.flushInput() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
        ser.flushOutput()#flush output buffer, aborting current output 
                 #and discard all that is in buffer

        #write data
        ser.write("AT+CSQ")
        print("write data: AT+CSQ")

       time.sleep(0.5)  #give the serial port sometime to receive the data

       numOfLines = 0

       while True:
          response = ser.readline()
          print("read data: " + response)

        numOfLines = numOfLines + 1

        if (numOfLines >= 5):
            break

        ser.close()
    except Exception, e1:
        print "error communicating...: " + str(e1)

else:
    print "cannot open serial port "
```

Вот здесь есть ещё другие примеры использования *pyserial*:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676172/full-examples-of-using-pyserial-package (англ.)

Comment: К сожалению это и другое не помогло. Понимаете, когда я подключаюсь через `ttyAMA0` с помощью `minicom`, предварительно убрав авторизацию `systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service` и отправляю `c`, у меня меняется разрешения выходящие на экран. При использовании этого кода, такого не происходит, я просто получаю `1` как ответ, либо к примеру `5`, если стоит `(b'hello')` - зависит от числа символов.

Comment: @Insider: getty на этом терминале быть, конечно же, не должно. Уберите его вообще напрочь. Посмотрите какие настройки порта в `minicom` (скорость, контроль чётности и тд). Если через minicom работает, то и через python заработает, никуда не денется

Comment: Вот так выглядят настройки `minicom` - `http://prntscr.com/c7nxtq`, а вот в питоне `http://prntscr.com/c7ny2k`. Предварительно деактивировал `getty`

Comment: @Insider: Вы учтите, что 1, которую возвращает `write` это не ответ устройства! Это всего лишь результат исполнения функции. Ответ вам надо читать `ser.read()` или `ser.readline()`

Comment: Я знаю, ответ бы я увидел на экране, сменилось бы разрешение экрана.

Comment: Но к сожалению, никаких изменений.

Comment: @Insider: А если просто echo -n c > /dev/ttyAMA0 делаете, работает?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44199/discussion-between-insider-and-igor-chubin).

Comment: Подсвкажите для чего `ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity, ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits, ser.flushInput() и ser.flushOutput()`